# How to prevent time selection from swapping automatically in antd rangepicker component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

This is antd's Rangepicker (taken from https://ant.design/components/date-picker), put inside antd's Form Item component.

```
<Form.Item
  name={name}
  label="Start/End Datetime"
  style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}
  rules={[
    {
      required: required,
      message: "This is a mandatory field",
    },
    {
      validator: (_, value) => customValidator(value)
    },
  ]}
>
  <RangePicker
    style={{ width: '100%' }}
    format={'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'}
    showTime={{ format: 'HH:mm' }}
    onCalendarChange={(dates) => {
      setStartDate(dates?.[0]);
      setEndDate(dates?.[1]);
    }}
    disabledDate={disabledDate}
    disabledTime={disabledRangeTime}
  />
</Form.Item>

const disabledRangeTime = (_, type) => {
if (type === 'start') {
  return {
    disabledHours: () =>
      endDate
        ? range(0, 24).splice(moment(startDate).add(1, 'hour').hours(), 24)
        : null,
    disabledMinutes: () => {
      if (endDate && moment().isSame(endDate, 'day'))
        return range(0, 60).splice(
          moment(startDate).add(1, 'minute').minutes(),
          60,
        );
      else return null;
    },
  };
}
return {
  disabledHours: () =>
    startDate ? range(0, 24).splice(0, moment(startDate).hour()) : null,
  disabledMinutes: () => {
    if (startDate && moment().isSame(startDate, 'day'))
      return range(0, 60).splice(0, moment(startDate).minutes());
    else return null;
  },
};};

const disabledDate = (current) => {
    return current && current < moment().startOf('day');
};
const range = (start, end) => {
const result = [];
for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
  result.push(i);
}
return result;};
```

Say I entered 3/16 10:00 as start date and 3/16 3:00 as end date, clicking ok swaps the times automatically which may go unnoticed and is bad user experience.

I found a prop called "order" mentioned in Timepicker docs (https://ant.design/components/time-picker) but setting prop to false doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there a way to stop the automatic swapping and instead throw a validation error?

Comment: I don't know how to stop the swapping, but check out 'disabledDate' and 'disabledTime' API, it may help you with the user experience.

Comment: Since time is always passing, setting disabled date becomes stale. If you disable start dates to never be before now, setting disabled date would disable dates up to that point. And start date eventually becomes stale while in picker mode which is why I decided on validating after selection. The problem increases when disabled end date depends on start date.

Comment: I think the disabled date won't be stale since 'disabledDate' and 'disabledTime' accept a function. The function can always return a new disabled date (starting date / ending date) depending on the selected date (ending date / starting date). The function is called every time a new time is selected.

Comment: I've updated the case to show you why it does. Yes, they accept a function but if user *stays* in the picker mode without clicking anything just browsing through the dates, the disabled time *relative to now* is stale. The whole crux of this issue is that user doesn't do any action and still gets to see a live update of disabled date or times relative to now while in picker mode.

I think I will just do validation on select without getting into this.